# How do i update text input value to use currency format

Tags: javascript, react-native, currency-formatting

This is my code  :

```
onChangeTextPrice(value) {
  const newPrice = parseInt(value, 10).toLocaleString(['ban', 'id']);
  return this.setState({ price: formatted });
}
```

If I `console.log(newPrice)`, it will give me the format, for example : `10.000.000`

but for some reason react native textinput doesn't use this value instead it show `10000000`.

but if I change `TextInput` value like this:

```
<TextInput
   keyboardType="numeric"
   value={'10.000.000'}
   multiline={false}
   underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
   onChange={val => this.onChangeTextPrice(val)}
```

It works. Why is that ?

Comment: I have never used react but reading this document seems giving the answer as this is masking and masking needs to be declared before initialization. https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text

Comment: I guess `keyboadType="numeric"` will result in an `input type="number"` which does only alow numbers without formating

Comment: Can you try this component 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-input

Comment: I use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask for the input masking.

Comment: @Pramod it didn't work

Comment: @UllasHunka Yes it worked thanks!!

Comment: @Shivam Thanks for the suggestion, i got the result i want with https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text

Comment: @williamanputra glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna use one of the following packages in order to achieve simple/complex input maskings.

[github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text](http://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text)

[github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask](http://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask)

A nice tutorial can be found [here](https://blog.cloudboost.io/text-input-mask-for-react-native-3c04e82843a6)